# Extended Tracking Vuforia Unity3d

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am trying to implement Extended tracking. Everything works fine,until user move device fastly. Basically I tracked an image and see 3d model. It remain in real world there If I move my camera here and there but at slow speed but if I move my device fastly 3d model will stick to view of my screen, which is not right. I guess its a bug in Vuforia.

Thanks,

Vanshika

Answer (score 1):

It is not a bug. Extended tracking uses the visual information in the camera images from frame to frame to try and keep track of where the camera is, relative to the trackable -- there is no other way, a camera does not have position-tracking hardware. If the device is moved slowly, successive frames of the camera will partly contain 'the same' things, and can try to determine its own movement from that information (although there will be some drift). When the camera moves too fast, there is no information shared from frame to frame for the camera to use to determine its own viewpoint change. I believe the 3d model will only 'stick' to your screen if you do not disable it / its renderer when tracking of it is lost, i.e. in an `OnTrackingLost()` type of method, as found in the `DefaultTrackableEventHandler`.